# Integral of complex questions?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, complex-numbers, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac {\sin x + \cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^2x}dx$$
$$\int e^x\cot x(\csc x-1)dx$$

These two integrals are impossible to find. If anyone knows how to integrate them please help me.

I am not able to differentiate it so I tried Integrals on wolfram.com and I got this answer :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As intimated above, split the first integral up as follows:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/4} dx \frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{\sin^4{x}+\cos^2{x}} &= \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/4} dx \frac{\sin{x}}{1-\cos^2{x}+\cos^4{x}}}_{u=\cos{x}} + \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/4} dx \frac{\cos{x}}{1-\sin^2{x}+\sin^4{x}}}_{u=\sin{x}}\\ &= \int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^1 \frac{du}{1-u^2+u^4} + \int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{du}{1-u^2+u^4}\\ &= \int_0^{1}\frac{du}{1-u^2+u^4}\end{align}$$

Now, the roots of the denominator are at $u^2=e^{\pm i \pi/3}$.  Split this integral up yet again by partial fractions:

$$\begin{align}\frac1{1-u^2+u^4} &= \frac1{(u^2-e^{i \pi/3})(u^2-e^{-i \pi/3})}\\ &= \frac1{i 2 \sin{(\pi/3)}} \left [\frac1{u^2-e^{i \pi/3}} - \frac1{u^2-e^{-i \pi/3}} \right ]\\ &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \Im{\left [\frac1{u^2-e^{i \pi/3}} \right ]}\end{align}$$

Now use the fact that

$$\int \frac{du}{u^2-a^2} = \frac1{2 a} \log{\left ( \frac{u-a}{u+a}\right )}+C$$

which may be derived using (what else?) partial fractions.  Note that in our case, $a=e^{i \pi/6}$ is complex so we do not have to worry about poles along the interval of integration.  So, we thus have:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{du}{1-u^2+u^4} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \Im{\left [\int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^2-e^{i \pi/3}} \right ]} \\ &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \Im{\left [\frac{1}{2 e^{i \pi/6}} \left [\log{\left ( \frac{u-e^{i \pi/6}}{u+e^{i \pi/6}}\right )} \right ]_0^1 \right ]}\\&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \Im{\left [\frac{1}{2 e^{i \pi/6}} \left [\log{\left ( \frac{1-e^{i \pi/6}}{1+e^{i \pi/6}}\right )} - \log{(-1)} \right ]\right ]}\\&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \Im{\left [\frac{1}{2 e^{i \pi/6}} \left [\log{\left ( (-i)\tan{\left ( \frac{\pi}{12}\right)}\right )} - \log{(-1)} \right ]\right ]}\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \Im{\left [e^{-i \pi/6} \left (\log{\tan{\frac{\pi}{12}}} + i \frac{\pi}{2} \right )\right ] }\\ &= \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\log{(2+\sqrt{3})}}{2 \sqrt{3}} \end{align}$$

Therefore

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} dx \frac{\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{\sin^4{x}+\cos^2{x}} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\log{(2+\sqrt{3})}}{2 \sqrt{3}}$$

A couple of notes about the result:

1) Mathematica returns $\frac{1}{12} \left(3 \pi +\sqrt{3} \log \left(7+4 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$.  This is equivalent to the derived result.  I leave it to the reader to prove that to him/herself.

2) I took $\log{(-i)} = \log{(-1)} + i \pi/2$, so that I got cancellation and didn't need to worry about the how to treat the argument of $-1$. Of course, I did take the argument of $i$ to be $\pi/2$, but that just means I used the principal value of the argument.

Comment: That is the correct answer but I want to know what this sign (Torque like sign) means and could this solution be a more simpler i.e. no imaginary part thing.

Comment: Also could you explain me the 5th step before the final answer?

Comment: @Hunter: use $i 2 \sin{x} = e^{i x} - e^{-i x}$ and $2 \cos{x} = e^{i x} + e^{-i x}$

Comment: Could you also do the 2nd part. Actually I am in 12th class and I don't think I have read about the above two equations. So it still confuses me.

Comment: @Hunter: 12th class?  Not sure what that means.  If that means you are still in high school and was presented with this integral without ever having seen fundamental relations of complex numbers, then I am afraid that someone is expecting too much from you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

-For the 1st one split it in two integrals. The first one let u = cosx, and the 2nd one let u = sinx. For each you can express sinx^4 interm of cosx and sinx.

-For the second one split it into two integrals and use integration by parts for each integral.

Comment: Man how to solve (1/(u^4-u^2+1))du. Cannot solve it. I know i have to use perfect square method but it comes out to be          (1/((t-1/2)^2)+3/4) and then apply dx/(x^2 + a^2) property but cannot apply it due to t^2 present.

Comment: You might want to look up the table of integrals book online.

Comment: Man Please could you be a more specific and tell me exactly what I am missing.

Comment: For $\frac{1}{(t-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}$, you need trig substitution $t=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\tan\theta$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's not \frac (1{t- \frac 1t) + \frac 34} but is \frac (1{t- \frac 1t)\pow 2 + \frac 34}

Comment: I still can't figure it out someone please help.

Comment: E-theory: did you actually try out your suggestion on the second integral?  If so and you were successful please share your wisdom.  If not, then please do not give out such hints as answers without carrying through the suggestions on your own.

Comment: of course i know, and i leave it for some ...beginners who needs to earn some points to do it.